# Google Analytics on Blogger site only shows mobile traffic (desktop traffic is filtered)

Tags: google-analytics, blogger

My Google Analytics only shows mobile traffic. Somehow my desktop traffic is getting filtered. I have not filtered any devices myself.

It's a Google Blogger site and the Universal Analytics ID is entered in the Blogger settings.

Comment: Sometimes blogger theme is coded differently for mobile version and desktop version, so it will be good to check the source code in both version. In desktop version of site, can you find Google analytic JavaScript code?

Answer (score 3):

Check that the blog's html template includes the following code before the closing `</head>` tag

```
<b:include data='blog' name='google-analytics'/>
```

If the above line of code is missing, as stated, paste it before the closing `</head>` tag

It is the include that adds your GA tracking id via the Blogger Settings option. Otherwise if the Settings option is used and the include is missing from the html template, it will only add the tracking to the mobile template.